# Position text in absolute center of html element

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to make a very simple x delete button i can use throughout this site i am building however, I can't ever seem to get it properly positioned...

This is it so far:

```
<button id="clear-input-location" name="clear-input-location">×</button>


#clear-input-location {
    display:block;
    background: #CCC;
    color: #FFF;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 26px;
}
```

see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kpheR/

Comment: What is the issue? Looks good to me in Chrome 27!

Comment: Not perfect enough, it's closer to the bottom than the top

Comment: @AndréFigueira If you want **exactly** the result as design, you should work with images.

Comment: @NOX you don't always need to rely on images... It is possible to get very good results with html and css which are cross browser compatible which in turn means less http requests or if using sprites, smaller sprite file sizes...

Comment: I agree with @NOX, you should do images if you want it pixel perfect. Fonts/text are notoriously innacurate between browsers on the pixel level because each browser uses a different text-rendering engine which causes them to render text in slightly different ways (slightly different sizes and such) which will make pixel perfection difficult at best. Nonetheless, removing the `font-weight: bold;` rule shows that it is centered, it just grows to the bottom and right due to the bolding (in Chrome 27).

Comment: You should match the `line-height` with the `height` attribute (26px)
http://jsfiddle.net/kpheR/5/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<div class="a">
  <button id="clear-input-location" name="clear-input-location">×</button>
</div>

.a{
  text-align:center;
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kpheR/2/)

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem... there isn't a horizontal alignment issue, but a vertical one.

Answer (score 0):

add `margin: 0 auto`; style to your text, this will center horizontally.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem... there isn't a horizontal alignment issue, but a vertical one.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by wrapping the × in a span then styling the span within to position the X properly. thanks anyway.

If anyone else needs this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/kpheR/3/

Comment: Well, for me, that is offset way too much to the top and right.

Comment: Looks fine on Chrome, I'm still going to now to other browser styles so it works everywhere...

Comment: Well, if you're happy with it... just be aware that fonts even vary between operating systems, not just between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.center-text {

text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;

}
```